# Magento admin panel not loading properly no options for login

Tags: magento2, admin, dashboard

I setup fresh **Magento 2.3** setup in my localhost. Frontend show properly but backend no options show login.
Admin panel not loading properly. Screenshot below:

[image]

- I clear all caches but admin panel not loading

Comment: Check in console there might be show error.

Comment: yes show errors

Answer (score 5):

This is a path issue. 
try editing the Validator file from **`vendor`** folder with namespace

> **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File**

At around line **138** replace code with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

save then **cache:flush**

Then check if it works.
Hope it helps

Comment: @Gagan , Please feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check What error you got in the error.log file?
Enable the developer mode by using the command **bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer** **you can get the error in screen itself** if you enable the developer mode.