# magento backend not access of After installation

Tags: magento2, error, installation

I install magento on window with Xampp and when I access backend it show black window can any body help me thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGFs2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a path issue. 
try editing the Validator file from vendor folder with namespace

> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File

At around line **138** replace code with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

save then **`cache:flush`**

Then check if it works.
Hope it helps

[solution reference with same issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255820/magento-admin-panel-not-loading-properly-no-options-for-login/255822#255822)

Comment: protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path), $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: this is function code where you add this line

Comment: protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories) { if (!is_array($directories)) { $directories = (array)$directories; } foreach ($directories as $directory) { if (0 === strpos(str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path)), $directory)) { return true; } } return false; }

check this one

Comment: not working after adding this code

Comment: protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Try this one

Comment: @Monukumar did it work?

Comment: not work same black window after add this code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87585/discussion-between-magefms-and-monu-kumar).

Comment: Please check if .htaccess file exists inside magento root folder