# Magento 2.3 Installation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I downloaded magento2.3 from Magento.com website and extracted to `"/var/www/html/mg"` but on `127.0.0.1/mg` i just see blank page.(white page with no error on console)

My PHP version is 7.2.x and Apache version is 2.4.
All PHP extensions are installed too.

I can install it from composer command line but still i can't see anything on front. also tried to `"index.php"` before pages but still doesn't work.

I think that it is because of mod_version of Apache2, but i don't know how to install it (.so)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page/252293?noredirect=1#comment360810_252293

Answer (score 0):

First, check reference here maybe same issue (possible duplicate)

> [magento backend not access of After installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255997/magento-backend-not-access-of-after-installation/255999#255999)

or

> run **static-content:deploy**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not on admin panel. i can't see anything at all even on front. i can not see setup page to install too!

Comment: updated the answer. check other solution

Comment: I can not install from front/setup page, so because it is not installed so i can't use any commands...

Comment: you said you installed in composer command line. hmmm check install directory write permission

Comment: I said i can do it by composer, i used all commands, but no changes

Comment: Somewhere i read apache2 mod_version is needed. but i can't enable it

Comment: stop your apache then try to edit httpd.conf and look for mod_version then enable, save then restart

Comment: How can i download mode_version.so and put it on /lib/etc...? i tried to upgrade apache2 but still doesn't have mod_version. i use ubuntu18.04

Comment: sorry not a linux user , but maybe you can reference this one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206039/magento-2-apache-mod-version-not-enabled-installed-allowed-by-host-causes-500