# How to fix error in magento 2.3.0

Tags: cms, magento2.3, page

When I go to my admin page, the Sign In panel which is supposed to display ,isn't displaying. Instead I'm only getting this plain background color.

The default store front (localhost/magento/) shows up with the basic header and footer with the message

`"CMS homepage content goes here."`

How to fix this error :

```
"CMS homepage content goes here."
```

[image]

Comment: check this solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255820/magento-admin-panel-not-loading-properly-no-options-for-login/255822#255822

Comment: You're using a version without media sample, try to install new one with media sample then you have everything from pages, products, categories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento admin panel not loading properly no options for login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255820/magento-admin-panel-not-loading-properly-no-options-for-login)

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a path issue.

Try to edit the Validator file from **`vendor`** folder with namespace.

> **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File**

At around line **138** replace code with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

save. Then cache:flush
```