# magento not installing showing just a black screen

Tags: magento2

**What should I do?**

I got this **error** after **Magento** installation.

[image: this is console log]

[image: this is admin page]

my magento version Magento-CE-2.1.16-2018-11-15-12-33-41

Comment: refer to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255820/magento-admin-panel-not-loading-properly-no-options-for-login/255822#255822

Answer (score 0):

try to run below commands on terminal

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Clear cache and provide 777 permission to var/* folders.