# Magento 2 Blank Page after successful installation

Tags: magento2

I install

`Magento version 2.3` with sample data on local server

- `Wamp PHP 7.2.4`
- `Apache 2.4.33`
- `MySQL 5.7`

After successfully install, my interface has nothing, as picture below.

**Please Help me!.**

**Thank you.**

[image]

Comment: did you check exception.log?

Comment: convert magento mode to developer and check exeption.log

Comment: did u run setup upgrade and static content deploy command?

Comment: and don't forget to check files/folders permissions accordingly documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: this should help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255820/magento-admin-panel-not-loading-properly-no-options-for-login?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Please see error log inside var/log/Exception file and share log

Comment: @ Trương Diệu My my answer is helpful for you ? If yes than please accept my answer and also upvote.

Answer (score 1):

In **core_config_data** Table

> **`Try This Query`**

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`=1 WHERE `path` = 'dev/static/sign';

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`=1 WHERE `path` = 'dev/template/allow_symlink';
```