# Magento 2.3.1 is not working in Xampp

Tags: frontend-error, magento2.3.1

I have successfully installed **Magento 2.3.1** in Xampp. But both the frontend and admin panel of the site are not working.

I have cleared the cache but still, it's not working.

Could anyone please help me with this?

[image]

Comment: you can refer here, this might be related https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255820/magento-admin-panel-not-loading-properly-no-options-for-login?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @magefms Thanks you very much. It's perfectly working. Please put this in the answer and i will mark it so that others who encounter this same issue will get output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing the Validator file from **`vendor`** folder with namespace

> **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File**

At around line **138** replace code with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

save then **cache:flush**

Comment: never manipulate files in vendor!

Comment: @PhilippSander as this is from local dev only and if you are using windows os

Comment: appreciate the downvote tho

Comment: no.... you can edit files in the vendor to test stuff. but it's NEVER a proper fix

Answer (score 0):

1. This might be caused by your PHP version compatibility with your Xampp.
2. Try to update the PHP version then try.