# Magento bad execution on js and css

Tags: javascript, css, magento2.3, admin-panel

i have a issue when a try to access to my Magento Admin Panel and frontend default page.

the admin panel always shows epmty And the frontend default page show content but without CSS and JS:

how to fix it?

Admin panel: [SS1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAp9x.png) Default Frontend: [SS2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSz1b.png) Using: Windows - Xampp - Magento 2.3 - Chrome Browser

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269104/magento-2-3-1-is-not-working-in-xampp/269111#269111

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your static content and clear your cache

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

If that doesn't resolve it, look at the permissions for the files.

Comment: I already did it but still the same result, how i can do that? (permissions for the files)

Comment: Do the files that are 404'ing in your console logs exist on your server in the path your browser is expecting? If yes, `ls -la` on the directory those files are contained in to see the permissions levels. You could also `rm -rf var/view-preprocessed` and `rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/` and then redeploy.

Comment: Not, the items that show error 404 are not in the specified folder i run the commands you provide and still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Magento 2.3 /pub/static/.htaccess file match the contents at [Magento 2.3's GitHub Repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.3/pub/static/.htaccess)?

Are you in Developer or Production mode?

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

Does this issue exist in developer mode?

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

If this issue exists only in production mode, then try:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento cache:flsuh
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Good Luck!

Comment: i will try... will send u the answer in couple minutes

Comment: php bin/magento deploy:mode:show -- > show "Default", php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer  -- > Broke the Magento i try to set restore using defualt ibut still magento is broke, i try the phps commands and still the same result. Thanks  for u help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just Open the

```
MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc/di.xml
```

and replace below code form line number 574

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

TO

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

and run below commands

```
rm -rf var/ generated/
```

run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean & php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
```

Comment: i will try... will send u the answer in couple minutes

Comment: i try but still the same result. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: in that case check permission of var and generated folders and also owner name of those directories.