# Magento 2.2.8 is not working in Xampp

Tags: localhost, xampp, magento2.2.8

I have installed Magento 2.2.8 in Xampp. After installed and done all the necessary things, I have checked the site in frontend but it seems the CSS is not loaded correctly. Please see the screenshot

[image]

In the Network tab, I'm getting these:

[image]

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: set developer mode and check if you are getting any error

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269104/magento-2-3-1-is-not-working-in-xampp?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: run php bin/magento s:s:d -f

Comment: @magefms I have already checked and it was the solution for Magento 2.3.1 and for me, the problem arose in Magento 2.2.8.

Comment: @Magentovsmarttec did you try to apply the same fix?

Comment: @magefms Yes I have tried but the coding in the file which you mentioned is different in Magento 2.2.8 when compared to Magento 2.3.1

Comment: what you got in your browsers network tab?

Comment: I have checked and see the network tab, it shows 404 for many of the JS files and the screenshot is attached in the question. The thing is, I have tried to install a third party theme and it was failed. I think this may the reason for this. If this is the case, how to solve this?

Comment: ah I see. check below answer

Comment: @Siva Did you find your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try, edit **`isPathInDirectories`** method with below code:

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos(str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path)), $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note: don't forget to redeploy static contents and run **`di:compile`** command

Comment: I haven't tested it but as you mentioned in the comment above, I think the above solution will work.

Comment: I have tried but it's not working as expected!

Comment: how'd you do it? You should first run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area frontend` then edit the **Validator** file. Save then run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: because the error seems to be caused by undeployed static files as mentioned in the comment above, you should check **pub/static/frontend** folder if static contents has been generated after running command for deploy static view files

Comment: Otherwise, you have to re-run again the static deploy command until you see the files are deployed in pub/static folder

Comment: and of course. don't forget to flush cache

Comment: Let me try and update you. Thanks for the steps

Comment: @Siva sure let me know if it works

Comment: Still not working. So finally I have reinstalled the Magento2.2.8 in local. Anyway thanks for following up.