# magento 2 installation on windows 10 problem

Tags: magento2

I tried to install **Magento 2** on windows10, wampserver, and xampp. both experiments got a successfully installed page.  But the localhost homepage does not work fine: homepage like the picture show. Create Account link does not work, `localhost/magento2/admin` does not work either.

Both wampserver and xampp have the same result. Did I miss something?

[image: Homepage]

[image: admin page]

Comment: Check this one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269104/magento-2-3-1-is-not-working-in-xampp?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Please update your URL
Now it is http://localhost/magento2/ to http://127.0.0.1/magento2/

This can be achieve from the Database table

> core_config_data

You have to update column named path

web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

And then please run all M2 command:

> php -d memory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php -d memory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Please check this.

Comment: Also, Please open this in firefox either chrome browser.