# How to install Magento Opensource 2.3.x on Windows 10

Tags: magento2.3, windows

I am new to Magento. I have read the requirements for Magento.
I dont have a linux box and I have to make do with my Windows one.

I am trying to install Magento 2.3 with sample data on XAMPP 7.3 by following
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-install-magento-2-windows.html.

I completed the installation. However when i hit localhost/magento
(i have named the dir as magento in htdocs), it doesnt load the static assets like
iamges, js, fonts.
So i get almost an empty page

When i inspected the page(in chrome browser) and i noticed that static assets
were not going loaded as most of the fonts, js etc were not there in pub/static dir.

I tried running magento setup:static-content:deploy -f to deploy the static files.

However there is no improvement and the page is empty (http://localhost/magento).

I am grateful for any help in resolving this issue.

Thanks

[image: Localhost Magento page]

Comment: Please check below url
==>
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279966/magento-2-installation-on-windows-10-problem

Comment: Have you looked into running linux in windows using hyper v? Long term could be easier. Or maybe docker via wsl https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/ plenty of magento 2 docker stacks available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Magento bug. Wrong paths to Windows are generated. The fixed fix is

**Magento 2.3.0 - 2.3.3**

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:140
```

the string

```
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

> to replace

```
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
   return true;
}
```

If You can't find out the (/vendor/magento/framework/) folder in **magento 2.2.7 - 2.3.3** . Then You can check it here:

```
#lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

And your other magento version check this link :-

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/252293/85907**

After change your run command :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Hello @IT guy check more link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269111/85907

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check

Comment: I followed your suggestion to replace the code at /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:140. It worked !! Thanks. I have marked the response accordingly