# After installing magento 2.1.17 admin login page cant display properly

Tags: admin, login

After installing Magento 2.1.7, When I am trying to open the admin panel login screen is blank and my console contains an error.if anyone has a solution then please let me know. 
I check in this file  -

> /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

in line number there is a code like :-:**138**

```
foreach($directories as $directory)
   {
     if(0===strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path),$directory))
     { 
      return true;
     }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the same with your own question before https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255820/magento-admin-panel-not-loading-properly-no-options-for-login?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I use this code but show errors

Comment: your error seems that you have deleted an htaccess inside your pub folder

Comment: download htacess from herehttps://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1/pub  and copy to your Magento project

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1/pub

Comment: try to run `php bin/magento setup:statuc-content:deploy -f`

Comment: I try all commands but admin panel not show

Comment: well try the second option, download pub folder in the link above then copy it to your magento project folder

Comment: I try but show same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92399/discussion-between-magefms-and-gagan).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this line like this:

```
foreach($directories as $directory)
   {
     if(0===str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path),$directory))
     { 
      return true;
     }
  }
```